# Is this "identity map" on presentations actually an identity map?

Tags: group-theory

I think the following is obvious. Is it?

> Suppose a map $\phi: \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n; r_1, \ldots, r_m\rangle\rightarrow \langle y_1, \ldots, y_n; s_1, \ldots, s_m\rangle$ between group presentations is such that $\phi(x_j)=y_j$ and $\phi(r_j)=s_j$ for all $i, j$*. Then $\phi$ defines an isomorphism of the underlying groups.

What is definitely true is that $\phi$ defines a surjective group homomorphism. Having been playing around with this for a while, I am unsure whether $\phi$ can have trivial kernel. However, I may be overthinking this problem and it is, indeed, obvious that $\ker\phi=1$.

*by "$\phi(r_j)=s_j$" I mean that the word $r_j$ is mapped to the word $s_j$, that is, $r_j(\phi(x_I))\equiv s_j(y_I)$.

Comment: Well, it is not that obvious after all if you are not sure...

Comment: Exactly! But I may just be getting tangled by the un-knot...

Comment: shouldn't it be easy to define the inverse map ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the statement. There has to be some relation between $r_i$ and $x_i$. Or maybe I don't understand the definition of "a map between presentations". For example obviously $<x;x^2>\to <y;y^3>$ does not extend to an isomorphism. It doesn't even extend to a homomorphism. I also don't understand the "*" remark. What does $r_j(\phi(x_I))\equiv s_j(y_I)$ mean? That product on the left seems illogical. What is $\equiv$? Could you give some concrete examples with a proper interpretation?

Comment: @freakish $r_j$ is a word over $x_I:=\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}^{\pm1}$. So by $r_j(\phi(x_I))$ I mean the same word but where the letter $x_j$ is replaced with $\phi(x_I)$.

Comment: @user1729 So I guess what you are really saying is that if $X,Y$ are two sets (alphabets) then we have a bijection $\phi:X\to Y$ which naturally induces a bijection between sets of words $\Phi: W(X)\to W(Y)$. And now if you have a subset $R\subseteq W(X)$ then we have an induced isomorphism $\eta:<X, R>\to <Y, \Phi(R)>$. The $\Phi$ function is the "replacement" you were talking about. Unlike the definition of $\equiv$ this is a formally correct approach. And with that it is trivial to define the inverse map. The only thing is to prove that $\eta$ is actually a well defined homomorphism.